# Asp.net checkbox renders span with AutoPostBack = true in it

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

This has got me at my wit's end. I have a GridView with a column with a checkbox in it. The checkbox is set to call CheckedChanged and AutoPostBack is true.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbNotifier" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="cbNotifier_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I am using similar code in the first column of the GridView and it works perfectly. I am using the code above in a different column. It does not work. Instead of rendering the checkbox to do a postback, it renders a span around the checkbox like this:

```
<span AutoPostBack="true"><input id="cbNotifier" type="Checkbox"></span>
```

so, of course, the checkbox will not postback.

If I add another, identical checkbox to the same column, like this ...

```
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbNotifier" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="cbNotifier_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbNotifier1" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="cbNotifier_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

... the second checkbox postsback perfectly, the first one gets the span tag around it. What on earth is going on?

Comment: Weird. What happens if you put `cbNotifier1` _above_ `cbNotifier` instead of below? Which one gets the `span`?

Comment: If I do that, cbNotifier1 still works correctly. cbNotifier (which is now the second control in the cell) is still getting the span tag with AutoPostBack="true" written in the tag. It's driving me nuts - if I delete cbNotifier, cbNotifier1 works okay. I have 8 gridviews with 3 columns with checkboxes in (all in a tabbed container) and some of the checkboxes work, and some don't.)

Comment: So it's specific to that name. I'm sure `cbNotifer` isn't special so there must be some other code somewhere affecting how it is rendered.

Comment: No - I have removed cbNotifier and changed the ID of cbNotifier1 to cbNotifier. It works. The other checkboxes not working are called cbFinalList. None of these checkboxes are referenced anywhere in code behind or elsewhere on the page. I'm on the point of giving up and putting LinkButtons that say 'Yes' or 'No' on the screen.

Comment: Okay, need to own up just in case anyone wastes their time looking at this. It was a bloody typo. I had typed AutoPostPack="true" on one the checkboxes - and then copied this all over the place while trying to resolve it. Because AutoPostPack="true" is meaningless - .net decided to render a span tag with AutoPostPack="true" in it. More haste, less speed. Have to forgive myself as I always seem to be working under pressure. Lesson for me to learn - if something has worked a thousand times before, and then doesn't work, I have done something wrong. 20 years of writing code - should have learned.